# Is 医好了 outdated in favour of 治好了?

Tags: vocabulary

I have been working through a grammar book with exercises where one of the solutions is "医生把病人医好了." My language partner said that 医好了 is unusual and that it is better to say 治好了 instead. Is this correct or is ti still OK to use 医好了? (I suspect that the main author of the grammar book is over 80; the book itself is less than 10 years old.)

Comment: This is totally anecdotal: 医好了 might be the old way of saying 治好了, but  if someone in real life uses it, it strikes me as dialectal rather than outdated.

Comment: users agree with l。p。，most commonly used verbs for ＂cure＂appear to involve 治，cf。jukuu：治愈、治疗、治、医治，also note
＂实用英语词典＂cure v （１）治好；医治（动）他的病治好了｜这种药能治好你的伤，i。e。 at least make it 医治

Comment: FWIW I've only ever seen the former (医好了) and _not_ the latter, but I am a native Cantonese speaker.

Comment: As a Hong Kong Cantonese, we mostly use 醫好咗 for "cured" colloquially. In SWC (Standard Written Chinese) which is Hong Kong's writing system, it seems that 治好了 is prefered. However, following our colloquial habit and write 醫好了 is quite acceptable in Hong Kong, I am curious about use of 醫好了 in non-Cantonese speaking regions, is it a common practice too?

Comment: Based on a [search in the TW domain](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%E6%B2%BB%E5%A5%BD%E4%BA%86+site%3Atw&ia=web),
治好了 is clearly much more common than 醫好了; I found very few isntances of the latter.
Based on a [search in the CN domain (the PRC)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%E6%B2%BB%E5%A5%BD%E4%BA%86+site%3Acn&ia=web), 治好了 is also clearly much more common than 医好了 in mainland China without Hong Kong. 
Thanks for pointing out that 医好了 / 醫好了 is commonly used among speakers of Cantonese.

Comment: @NS.X.  I think so as well. When I speak in Sichuan dialect, I usually say 医好了, rather than 治好了. To me, 治 is somehow literary, as 治 can also mean to manage,  to govern,  to harness. There is even an idiom that might confuse a foreign learner: 不治身亡. Which means someone dies because the medical treatment doesn't CONTROL the disease, however, literally, you might think it means one dies because no medical treatment is given.

Answer (score 2):

医好了, to me, is more often used in old times, that's why it's totally ok to say that in HongKong, considering HK is still using traditional Chinese. In modern Chinese, 治好了 is more natural, but in some formal occasion we can use 医 and 治 together as one verb, i.e. 医治

examples:

张医生医好了无数病人。(it's ok, but less used in daily communication, I would use it in a composition, or in HK maybe? I don't know since I didn't go there)

张医生医治了无数病人。(sounds formal, I would use it in a report)

张医生治好了无数病人。(sounds more familiar and nature, I use it in my daily life)

Answer (score 1):

I think 医好了 is always used in traditional Chinese medicine.

In Chinese, you can use "医治", so you can say 医生把病人医治好了. same as "医好了" or "治好了"

There is nothing different between these three word. Everybody can understand them. but we use "治好了" more than "医好了"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Echo Z. 治好了 is more common although the other one is not uncommon. There is 医治 as a verb such as in 医治病人。Also, 他的病没得医/没得治.

Answer (score 0):

Daily use:
In Mandarin native (especially north/middle china), 治好了 is the common expression, but in Canton or Fujian culture(including Guangxi/Hong Kong/Macao) 医好了 are much more often in native use.

Official use:
治好了 can have more meaning than 医好了 in different contexts, while 医好了 can only express 'cured'.

Answer (score -1):

As a native speaker, it's "治好了" more in common use and colloquial. “医好了” is a a kind of usage in ancient prose, we occasionally use in written language.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Being a Cantonese native speaker, we use 医好了 much more common than 治好了。

Answer (score -2):

普通话的确说“治好了” 多一些， 按照北方语系的习惯，  只好了更加口语话而且用于更多的语言环境。

治好了， 可以有 医好了， 治理好了， 管理好了， 等等其他的意思（依照语境不同， 更加灵活）

Comment: Q is Eng, best to answer in base language.